# check for presence in a list django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to check if a value belongs to a list in django template. Something like this

`{% if value in ['Pass','Fail'] %}`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is sad, that Django does not support this.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I don't think that you can define a list directly in the template. You could pass a list to the template and do

```
{% if value in my_list %}
```

For example:

```
{% if name in 'foo,bar' %}
    bla
{% endif %}
```

---

Alternatively, you could write a template tag which takes parameters like this:

```
{% ifinlist value "val1,val2,val3" %}
```

Comment: @sunnyiitkgp, **ifinlist** does not exist in Django by default. It could be a template tag you could write yourself.

Comment: Answer could be improved by showing a full solution, i.e. how to setup and pass `my_list` into the template or how to write `ifinlist`.

Comment: The `'foo,bar'` example here is not applicable/incorrect, as `'foo,bar'` is a string, not a list.

Comment: in the case {% if name in 'foo,bar' %}  name='o,b' would evaluate True!!! is this what we want ?

Comment: the thing is if you check {% if 'foo' in 'foo_bar,fool' %}
it would still be true.. as "in" doesnt care about the commas it just checks if its in the string  'foo_bar,fool'

Answer (score 25):

You could write the if condition as

`{% if value in 'Pass,Fail' %}`

No need of template tag or list from backend

Comment: Check the doc. You can't do that in django templates, you do need a list first.

Comment: @EmilioConte this method works fine for lists of strings as in the question, see [the docs on the in operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator). For instance, if `value = 'Pass'`, then 'Pass' is a substring of 'Pass,Fail'.

Comment: @YPCrumble 'Pass,Fail' is not a list of strings but a string itself. This method works to test if ```value``` belongs to a chain of characters. The OP's question is about a **list** not a ```str```. But you're right I was wrong, It's a valid method and I'll remove this useless post.

Comment: This is actually only valid if you don't care about matching substrings. For example `if 'a' in 'Pass,Fail'` would be `True` for either "item". It therefore is only useful for simple, disparate comma-separated strings of characters.

Comment: This is not good, when I got 3 String Long Sword, Sword, Short Sword. If Value is Sword, and in 'Long Sword, Short Sword' it will be return True when it should be false.

Answer (score 12):

Django Template:

```
{% value|ifinlist:"val1,val2,val3" %}
```

Template Tag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='ifinlist')
def ifinlist(value, list):
    return value in list
```

Comment: Parameter shouldn't be called `list` - it shadows built-in name.

Answer (score 2):

How to pass a list to your template? I personaly use `extra_context` attribute in generic views like this:

```py
class MyObjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyObject
    template_name = "path/to/object_detail.html"
    extra_context = {'DISABLED': [model.ACCEPTED, model.REFUSED]}
```

Then in my template, for example, to disable btn:

```html
<input class="btn"{% if object.status in DISABLED %} disabled="disabled"{% endif %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this answer because none of the above actually solved the problem efficiently (when efficiency means: not passing more values to a template while still iterating over a list, not a string)

I did this in my template:

```
{% if content.status|in_list_from_csv:"C,P,Q" %}
```

and then added this filter: ([if you don't know what filters are](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/custom-template-tags/))

```
@register.filter(name='in_list_from_csv')
def in_list_from_csv(value, csv):
    my_list = csv.split(",")
    return value in my_list
```

The difference of this from the previous answers is that:

- 1: It does not iterate chars on a string, thing that the others answers do;
- 2: You don't need to pass extra values to your template.