# How can I use literal list in Django template file?

Tags: django-templates

From a Django template file I want to check if my variable myVar is "A" or "B" (or "C" or "D", etc..).
So I would like to do something like this:

```
{% if myVar in ["A", "B"] %}
    Hello
{% else %}
    World
{% endif %}
```

But this gives me a syntax error in the first line.

How then can I use a literal list in the Django template file?

Answer (score 0):

you can't define a list directly in the template. You could pass a list to the template  using a view in views. py and a url in urls. py
ex:In views. py

```
def view_name(request):
    list_name=['A', 'B', 'C'];
    render(request, 'directory/template_name.html'
    {'list_name':list_name})
```

In urls. py

```
urlpatterns = [
               path('index/', views.view_name, name='main-view'),
 ]
```

In template

```
{% if myVar in list_name%}
Hello
{% else %}
World
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -5):

The answer can be found here: [check for presence in a list django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481750/check-for-presence-in-a-list-django-template)

This question is essentially a duplicate.

Comment: The referenced answer iterates over a list variable The op is asking about a list literal.